# How can I use a CSS gradient on both top-left and top-right corners of my page?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to figure out how I can use this:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

And use one in the top-left corner of my page, as well as top-right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/6SMXu/2/) (I stripped some extra code out, best viewed in Chrome), using 2 wrappers and applying a gradient to each (provided each ends up transparent to allow the other to show through).

The gradient code I used to generate this is:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, ellipse cover, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 50%);
    border:solid 1px red;
}

#inner {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top right, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,0) 50%);
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

Here's my demo result:

[image]

Alternately, you could combine both gradients into one using the [Colorzilla editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), using multiple color stops.